# como puedo abrir un direcctorio en disco H: si mi programa esta ubicado en disco C:

Tags: php, rutas

Buen día espero que me puedan ayudar con su conocimiento, soy nuevo en **php**, mi programa esta en **C:\xampp\htdocs\viva\index.php** y necesito abrir una carpeta con **operdir()** en otro disco **H:respaldo\vivai6**, ¿cual seria la ruta necesaria para llegar hasta ahí? gracias

Comment: Hola @oxse por favor edita tu pregunta y escribe el código que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora, para poderte ayudar mejor y cual seria el error que te estada dando con la **ruta**. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit] para agregar toda la información que falta en tu pregunta.